# Can I connect 2 standard 12V 2A wall adapters in series?

Tags: transformer

I live in the UK and I need a 24VDC power supply. They are very expensive.

Can I just use 2 cheap standard 240VAC - 12VDC wall adapters in series with no issues to achieve 24VDC?

For example, and so I'm clear, my phone charger is 240VAC - 5VDC 2 ampere, can I just wire 2 in series for 10VDC 2 ampere output?

If yes, my understanding is that it would give me the same current as the lowest current transformer and I should remove the earth wire from 1 wall plug so as to make sure the outputs are isolated.

Comment: There is no logic to prove if you connect two 5V supplies in series and it worked that it will work for two 12V supplies.  They must be floating to work.

Comment: I see prices between £4 and £12 so that makes your question somewhat founded on a misconception. Given the hassle and the uncertainty around what you might end up with, I wouldn’t recommend putting two in series.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting two power supplies in series is possible, if they have isolated/floating output.

It means that they must have ungrounded 2-prong mains plugs to begin with, or in case of grounded 3-prong mains plug, the output must be said to be isolated/floating so that it is not internally connected to ground inside the power supply.

Devices with 3-prong grounded mains plug must have the ground connected; do not modify and remove the ground (earth) wire, it is not what you want, and it may be hazardous.